# Restriction on distance between two points in a dense subset.

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, metric-spaces, coloring, combinatorial-geometry

Consider a metric space $(M,d)$. Under what conditions is it the case that there exists some dense subset $D$ of $M$ such that
$$\forall x,y \in D \, d(x,y) \neq 1$$
So far I have proven that such a dense subset exists in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by taking rationals with odd numerator and denominator, and I conjecture that such a subset exists for all second countable metric spaces.

Comment: A counter-example for your conjecture is $\mathbb N$ with discrete metric.

Comment: In any normed linear such  a dense set exists.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy it follows for Banach spaces from my solution for $\mathbb{R}^n$, right? Regarding the conjecture, does adding the condition that the space has a proper dense subset circumvent the counterexample (and related ones) that you gave? Or rather, requiring that the metric take on all real values (or something of the sort)?

Comment: Suppose $M=A\cup B$ where $A\ne \phi\ne B,$ and $\forall a,a'\in A\;(d(a,a')\le 1/2 )$ and $\forall b,b'\in B\,(d(b,b')\le 1/2) $ and $\forall a\in A\,\forall b\in B\,(d(a,b)=1).$ Then $M$ may have a dense proper  subset, and may have no isolated points, but any dense $D\subset M$ must contain some $a\in A$ and some $b\in B.$ ...........I wonder if there is a $connected$ counter-example